# Centre Buttons horizontally and vertically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and I am trying to centre a component I created vertically and horizontally. IF I place the centre style code in the overall view it works but then this makes everything in the app.js centre as well. There should be a way to only centre the component I made.

I have tried to changing the flex and the diff flexbox options.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    Animated,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Button,
    Alert,
    TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';
import Animater from './components/Animater';
import PresentationalComponent from './components/PresentationalComponent';

const AnimatedButton = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TouchableHighlight);

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listDataFromChild: null
        };
    }

    myCallback = (dataFromChild) => {
        this.setState({ listDataFromChild: dataFromChild });
    }

    render() {

      return (
        <View >     
          <Text style={styles.score}>
            Score: {this.state.listDataFromChild}
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Animater  callbackFromParent={this.myCallback}/>     
          </View>
        </View>
        //<PresentationalComponent color = {[animatedStyle]} showAlert = {this.showAlert}/>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,

    },
    score: {
        fontSize: 30,
        alignItems: 'center',
        top: 100,

    },
});
```

I expected the Animater component to be centre but instead it remains in the top left corner of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To align item in center with position: 'absolute' you have to add following style**

```
 {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
```

**Also please make main container with flex:1**

```
{ flex: 1 }
```

[image]

**Complete code**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class Home1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.score}>Score: 50</Text>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Animator container</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: { flex: 1 },
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  score: {
    fontSize: 30,
    alignItems: "center",
    top: 100
  }
});
```

Comment: Just so I understand is there another way to do it without position absolute?

Comment: if you do not want to use "absolute" ,  it depends how much height view has, if flex:1 then view have full height and width and item in center of screen  . if view does not have flex:1 then view will be center of width and height content have . Also you can use  "alignself" in style to make view in center

Answer (score 0):

Your style should be,

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
}
```

**Note:** When working with `flex` we don't need `position` property.

Comment: I attempted this but I received an error: [ESLint] 'flex' in not defined (no-undef)

Comment: Try couting flex like display: 'flex'

Comment: Is the error throwing for same line? Or you have used flex somewhere else? Check if there any flex used.

Comment: Remove position: absolute and display:  flex.

Answer (score 0):

I share with you how to center a button horizontally in react native.

```
.test1 {
flexDirection: "row",
justifyContent: "center",
alignItems: "center",
},
```